# New Visa Waiver law

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian Citizens born in Canada to Iranian parents, I have never been to Iran nor have I ever applied for Iranian citizenship, but it seems like that doesnt matter and youre considered "Iranian" regardless.

Does this mean I now need a visa to go to the USA?

Comment: As noted, the VWP does not affect Canadians; but for others reading this, the changes to the VWP are all still proposals, they have not been approved or implemented and are subject to changes.

Comment: @jpatokal apparently, the change was signed into law already.  It is to be implemented next year, but the details have of course not yet been worked out.  Frankly it seems like a horrific Pandora's box of regulatory ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

No, Canada is not part of the Visa Waiver Program, and therefore changes to VWP do not affect Canadian citizens.

Comment: Ok cool! Thank you very much for your reply! I had no idea Canada was "separate" from other countries not needing a visa